# Tools for etching leather?

Tags: leather, tool-identification

There’s this artist who I absolutely love, and they etch leather using a tool I am not familiar with. I want to get into this style of art and was wondering if you had any ideas! There is a pic attached, taken as a screenshot from a video so a bit blurry, but any clues as to what the tool is would be amazing.

[image]

Comment: Hi Hanna, could you add the source for the image?

Answer (score 5):

Based on the appearance of the tool (the thick shaft and the guard around it), the person in the video is drawing on the leather using heat, rather than 'cold' etching, carving, or engraving the leather. This is known as [pyrography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrography).

The tool used here is called a '***solid-point burner***'.
This tool is attached to a power source, often (and preferably) has temperature controls, and produces heat leading to a tip that can often be changed for improved surface control (see upper tool in image below).

A common alternative, which is quicker to work with and allows for more control over temperatures and surface contact, is the '*wire-nib burner*' (see lower tool in image below).

[image]
<sup>[source](https://toolmonger.com/2013/01/17/the-art-of-pyrography/) | [source](https://truart.co/product/truart-dual-pen-professional-woodburning-detailer/)</sup>